# How to get the last day of a specific month

Tags: vb.net, date-formatting

I have textbox for inserting date called **startdate**.

What I want is that when the user inserts a date, I should get the last day of month in another textbox.

For example: 
Startdate: 23/09/2018 "my format is dd/mm/yyyy"

Lastdate: 30/09/2018

Comment: See: [DateTime.DaysInMonth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.daysinmonth?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.DateTime.DaysInMonth);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2)) and [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: And check out the month format (mm -> MM)

Comment: *"I have textbox for inserting date"*.  Why?  Why aren't you using a `DateTimePicker`?

Comment: `How to get last day of specific date` How many days does each date have where you live?

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the program you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: I saw a clever one where they added one to the month, then created a date the first on the new month and subtracted one from the day. @Gabriel Stancu answer is much better. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think the following code is what you need:

```
Dim MyDate As Date = Date.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
Dim DaysInMonth As Integer = Date.DaysInMonth(MyDate.Year, MyDate.Month)
Dim LastDayInMonthDate As Date = New Date(MyDate.Year, MyDate.Month, DaysInMonth)
TextBox2.Text = LastDayInMonthDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Hope this helps! ^^

Comment: Please avoid answering [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) fodder. Instead, close it and move on.

Comment: Will do, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: It helped me alot   thank you so much